# Youtube modal not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm implementing a plugin to load youtube videos in a modal (https://appleple.github.io/modal-video/). The problem is with the cross button in the modal.

If I do not refresh the page, click the cross button on the modal and then click on the video again, the click event fires twice instead of once ie. I get two modals.

My JS for running this is fairly simple:

HTML code:

```
<a id="runVideo"  data-video-id='XXXXXXX' class="white">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle"></span> Want to know how we do that? Watch our video.
</a>
```

JS code:

```
$( "#runVideo" ).click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  console.log("mydick");
  $("#runVideo").modalVideo({channel:'youtube'});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if you ever want some click event to happen only once, we gotta unbind the click handler everytime it is clicked. So, something like this worked out

```
$('#runVideo').bind('click', function() {
       $(this).unbind('click');
       alert('Clicked and unbound!');
       $("#runVideo").modalVideo({channel:'youtube'});
});
```